# Program prints garbage instead of the actual returned value from a function call

Tags: c, function, pointers, printf, return-value

I wrote an algorithm to extract words from a string and store them in an array,however i am getting an unwanted result and I can't figure out why.The output is being a very weird characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

char *extract(char *String)
{
char str[10][20];
int x = -1,y = 0,z = 0;
for( size_t n = 0 ; n < strlen(String) ; n++ )
{
    y++;
    if( String[n] == ' ' ) y = 0, z = 0;

    if( y == 1 ) x++;

    if( y > 0 )
    {
        str[x][z] = String[n];
        z++;
        str[x][z] = '\0'; //Comment this*********
    }
}

/*for( int n = 0; n < 10; n++ ) Uncomment this*****
{
    str[n][3] = '\0';
}*/

    return str[7];
}

int main()
{
    printf( "WORD : %s\n",extract("POL POL POL POL POL POL POL POL POL POL") );
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

where is the bug in this code?

Note: i also get weird characters when i use printf and strlen somewhere else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem as I can see here, `str` is a local variable to the function `extract()` and you're trying to return it's address, and use that returned value as an argument to `printf()`. It invokes UB.

To clarify, `str` will exist until `extract()` finishes execution. Once it finishes ith execution and returns to the caller, there won't be any existence of `str`. So, the returned pointer will point to an *invalid* memory location. Using that retrun value further will lead to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Here's a working example without UB that copies the result into an output buffer: http://ideone.com/54aZh0